# Cordova file plugin not working for android sdk 30

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an app with Cordova 8.1.2. Everything was working until i upgrade Cordova 10 and android sdk version to 30. After upgradation reading external file system not working in android for api 30.

Can you please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the small amount of information given, all I can provide you with is the changes in the file system with the release of Android 11(sdk 30) - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score -1):

you will have to change back to Android 9 (sdk 28) check if it is running fine then upgrade back to sdk 30. probably you encountered some error along the line.